# Can std::atomic_flag be safely destroyed after calling notify_all?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, c++20, lifetime

In my code, I want to use a [`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) to synchronize two threads. Specifically, I would like to use the new [`wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/wait) and [`notify_all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/notify_all) features that are introduced in C++20.

In a nutshell: one thread is waiting for the flag to become ready while another thread will set the flag and issue the notification. The catch, however, is that the `atomic_flag` lives on the stack and will be destroyed after the notification, while the first thread may still be in the call to `wait`.

Basically, I have something equivalent to the following snippet:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

int main(int, char**)
{
    auto t = std::thread{};

    {
    auto f = std::atomic_flag{};
    t = std::thread{[&f] { f.wait(false); }};

    // Ensures that 't' is waiting on 'f' (not 100% guarantee, but you get the point)
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{50});

    f.test_and_set();
    f.notify_all();
    } // <--- 'f' is destroyed here but 't' may still be in the wait call

    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

In the past, I have used `boost::latch` for situations like this and I know from experience that this pattern will nearly always crash or assert. However, replacing `boost::latch` with `std::atomic_flag` has not resulted in any crashes, asserts, or deadlocks.

**My question:** is it safe to destroy a `std::atomic_flag` after a call to `notify_all` (i.e. with waking threads potentially still in the `wait` method)?

Comment: I believe it's a race. `wait` is defined as checking the value of the flag after waking up, comparing it with its argument (and perhaps going back to sleep). This would race with the destructor.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, indeed. And I've managed to fairly quickly break the working code snippet to make it deadlock. There is indeed a race between the waking thread reading the atomic flag's value and the destroying thread destructing the atomic flag.
In the C++ standard, the effects of the wait also describe that after waking, the thread will read the flag's value again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, it is not safe.

## From the standard

In the standard (`[atomics.flag]`), the effects of `atomic_flag_wait` are described as follows:

> Effects: Repeatedly performs the following steps, in order:
>
> - Evaluates `flag->test(order) != old`.
> - If the result of that evaluation is `true`, returns.
> - Blocks until it is unblocked by an atomic notifying operation or is unblocked spuriously.

This implies that, after unblocking, the `std::atomic_flag` is accessed to read the new value. And thus, it is a race with destructing the atomic flag from the other thread.

## In practice

Probably, the code snippet works fine because the destructor of `std::atomic_flag` is trivial. So the memory is left intact on the stack and the waiting thread can still continue to use those bytes as if they were the atomic flag.

By modifying the code a bit to explicitly zero the memory where the `std::atomic_flag` lived, the snippet now deadlocks (at least on my system).

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <thread>

int main(int, char**)
{
    auto t = std::thread{};

    // Some memory to construct the std::atomic_flag in
    std::byte memory[sizeof(std::atomic_flag)];

    {
    auto f = new (reinterpret_cast<std::atomic_flag *>(&memory)) std::atomic_flag{};

    t = std::thread{[&f] { f->wait(false); }};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{50});
    f->test_and_set();
    f->notify_all();
    
    f->~atomic_flag(); // Trivial, but it doesn't hurt

    // Set the memory where the std::atomic_flag lives to all zeroes
    std::memset(&memory, 0, sizeof(std::atomic_flag));
    }

    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Which will deadlock the waiting thread if it happens to read the atomic flag's value after the memory has been set to all zeroes (probably because it now interprets those zeroes as 'false' for the atomic flag's value).